# Объединить два списка в третий так, чтобы одинаковые элементы из разных списков не повторялись

Tags: python

Список `lst1` содержит меню блюд `['Snacks', 'Caesar Salad', 'Spaghetti','Chicken Stirfry']`, а список `lst2` содержит `['French Fries', 'Caesar Salad','Fish and Chips', 'Chicken Stirfry', 'Juice']`.
Напишите программный код,который добавляет блюда, которые не повторяются, из второго списка в первый.
В начале я попыталась соединить списки

```
lst1 = ['Snacks', 'Caesar Salad',' Spaghetti','Chicken Stirfry']
lst2 = ['French Fries', 'Caesar Salad','Fish and Chips', 'Chicken Stirfry', 'Juice']
print(lst1+lst2)
```

Не знаю как сделать чтобы вывел результат без повторений

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в чем проблема?
циклом проверить существует ли элемент в 1 листе, и если нет добавить его туда.
первый список преобразовать в множество перед проверкой, для быстроко поиска

```
lst1 = ['Snacks', 'Caesar Salad',' Spaghetti','Chicken Stirfry']
lst2 = ['French Fries', 'Caesar Salad','Fish and Chips', 'Chicken Stirfry', 'Juice']
set_lst1 = set(lst1)
for el in lst2:
    if el not in set_lst1 :
        lst1.append(el)

print(lst1)
```

Comment: В том и дело, что перед проверкой, а не внутри нее. Сейчас он создается в цикле каждый раз, что скорости точно не способствует, лучше уж просто `in lst1` использовать.

Comment: @EzikBro да точно.

Answer (score 2):

сложи два списка, с помощью метода set преобразуй его в множество, которое по определению содержит только уникальные элементы, а затем конвертирую обратно в список методом list если нужно